# Node.JS and Terminology

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

Excuse my ignorance, but I'm trying to wrap my head around the whole Node.js vs Backbone.js thing. I think I'm figuring it out, could somebody verify this or help adjust my understanding?

Node.js is a platform which can serve and render HTTP?

Express.js is a framework for Node.js and handling routes?

Backbone.js is a front-end Javascript library which is not dependent on Node.js at all?

Is it common/acceptable to serve the Backbone.js HTML from Node+Express, or would another platform be better suited?

Comment: First three are correct; is the only real question #4?

Comment: Backbone.js is a JavaScript library that is _supposed_ to make it easy to write good code and enforce separation of concerns between the view and the model layers of your code. It's not coupled to HTML at all. (Not a fan)

Comment: I'm learning and wrote a simple app in Node+Express. I was going to try and learn Backbone by turning it into a SPA. And all the tutorials I saw on Backbone never mentioned how to serve the HTML which housed Backbone application.

Comment: You can serve the frontend backbone application using any server that serves static files (IIS, Apache, Node/Express, etc or even local files - with some browser security settings caveats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Node.js vs Backbone.js, that's almost analogous to trees vs apples :)

Node is an environment for running JavaScript on a server.  Backbone is a library for manipulating JavaScript in front or back-end applications.  To answer your questions specifically:

> Node.js is a platform which can serve and render HTTP?

Yes, but that is only one of [many other uses](http://nodejs.org/api/).

> Express.js is a framework for Node.js and handling routes?

Not just routes, it is a framework for structuring Node.js web applications.  I would suggest the book [Smashing NodeJS](http://smashingnode.com/) which takes you through building a web server and then shows how Express manages most of what you would have to do yourself.

> Backbone.js is a front-end Javascript library which is not dependent on Node.js at all?

It is definitely not dependent on Node, but it *can* be used within the Node environment (since Node just runs JavaScript).

> Is it common/acceptable to serve the Backbone.js HTML from Node+Express, or would another platform be better suited?

This shouldn't be asked on StackOverflow as it does not have a definitive answer.  I would recommend a Google search for "node web frameworks" if you are looking for some recommendations, but it sounds like you should learn a bit more about web development before worrying about which framework to use.

Comment: That's why I'm here asking questions. I'm not worried about which framework to use, I'm just trying to figure out which *.js thing belongs to which pile. I'm trying to get my head wrapped around the entire "stack" which makes up a web app, but most of the Backbone stuff I had read was only concerned with the front-end. But it's coming together. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be condescending or discourage you from asking questions, just want to make sure you don't get lost in the JS jungle before picking up the fundamentals.